# How to get the name of a class of a method as NSString?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I need the name of the class that owns a method, as `NSString`. Example: There's a `-fooBar` method inside a `SomeClass`, and that `-fooBar` method runs some code. This code must print out what class "owns" it, I mean: What class that method belongs to. So I can't hard-type the class name in a `NSString` because I need that for debugging purposes, determining dynamically the name of the class. Hard to explain. Any idea?

Answer (score 64):

On the Mac, you can use:

```
NSString *className = [self className];
```

or

```
NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
```

On the iPhone, `[self className]` doesn't exist so you'll have to use:

```
NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
```

Answer (score 10):

```
NSLog(@"%@",[self className]);
```

Update: sorry, I didn't realize className didn't exist on the iPhone.
As the above comment suggested; use ..

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([self class]));
```

.. instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
[[self class] description]
```

Comment: You'll get a little more than you wanted like so: <SignInViewController: 0x17e50510>